# Why must we convert everything to a char* when we write it to a file?

Tags: c

Out of curiosity, why are we converting something to a char* when we write it to a ( binary ) file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the typical I/O functions that write, take a pointer to `char`. This is because someone considered that the most representative way of talking about the data stored in a binary file; it's just a bunch of the machine's smallest adressable word, in sequence. The C type name for that is `char`.

Answer (score 7):

`char*` merely represents a pointer to the beginning of a sequence of bytes, which is exactly what one expects a binary file to contain.

Answer (score 2):

Unwind and vezult have already answered your question, and I assume you know what a pointer is. But just in case you think of *converting something to a char** as an operation that actually somehow changes your data in memory (and, for example, may take more time if there's a lot of data) then note that such is *not* the behavior of getting a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about `fread()` and `fwrite()`? The data they read or write are passed as `void*` (or `const void*`), so you don't have to convert.

But in C++ when you use, say, [`istream::read()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/), then the pointer to the reception buffer must be passed as a `char*`, so there is no implicit conversion.